# SQL server datatype int Vs Big int

Tags: sql-server-2008, types

I created a table with column id as int data type. However, I realized that int type may not be able to hold some of the values I might put in the table. I wish to find out, if I define the column as bigint, does it take up "space" or does it use space on the database EVEN before I put a value in the column? I am using sql server 2008 R2. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

int always uses 4 bytes, bigint always uses 8 bytes. The actual value stored does not affect the size of the field.

Comment: thanks alot. Just one more query. If I have int "124" on a bigint column, will this use 3 characters by 8 bytes space?

Comment: This isn't entirely true... if you implement data compression, it will be able to reduce the space used if not all bytes are required. The value "124" can fit into the space required by a `TINYINT` under compression. However Jim please be careful not to count characters and make some assumption that it correlates directly to number of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you enter any number, even 1, it will use the full 8 bytes. So the extra storage overhead is 4bytes * number of rows. If you are worried that you numbers will grow higher than 2,147,483,647, then you should use bigint.

Comment: @Spencer...thanks alot. sorry I did not see the answer earlier...makes sense now. Chris thanks to.